# Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to JAXBElement<User>

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

i have a prob with a cast

```
JAXBElement<User> jaxbElement = (JAXBElement<User>)unmarshaller.unmarshal(sr);
```

It's doesn't work , eveybody can help me ?

---

I can't do this : 
i show you my code :

```
StringReader sr = new StringReader(this.message);
JAXBElement<Utilisateur> jaxbElement = (JAXBElement<Utilisateur>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(sr);
```

if I do this, I have an error because i Use a StringReader :

```
JAXBElement<User> jaxbElement = unmarshaller.unmarshal(sr, User.class);
```

Comment: What do you mean: "It doesn't work"? Could you be a little bit more specific?

Comment: You realise that the message you quoted is just a compiler warning, right?  It doesn't actually stop your code from compiling.  So tell us, is something else wrong?

Comment: it's a compilator warning yes , My code can't continue  , i can't show this
System.out.println(jaxbElement.getName());

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to avoid the compiler warning you can use one of the unmarshal methods that takes a `Class` parameter.

```
JAXBElement<User> jaxbElement = unmarshaller.unmarshal(sr, User.class);
```

**Note**

Your code should run perfectly fine as you have it in your question.

Comment: I Can do this with a StringReader ?

Comment: @Hann - You will need to wrap your `StringReader` in a `StreamSource`.

Comment: thanks it's work , but i can't show jaxbElement or jaxbElement.getName() in a system.out.println()

Comment: @Hann - What happens when you try to do that?

Comment: I need to have my Qname but it's worked. Thanks Blaise